# MFC draw a cross line using OnMouseMove

Tags: mfc, mousemove, bitblt

As follow code, I want use mpDC to draw a cross line on mouse point, 
when I move the mouse, the cross line will shift with my mouse point,

but maybe I dont know the usage of BitBlt, so I cant see any line in my draw area 
(rectRange),

```
    CWnd *pWnd;
    CRect rect;
    CDC mShowDC;
    CBitmap mShowBmp;
    CPen mpen;
    CPen *mOldpen;

    CDC *mpDC;

    mpDC = GetDC();

    mShowDC.CreateCompatibleDC(mpDC);
    mShowBmp.CreateCompatibleBitmap(mpDC,rectRange.Width(),rectRange.Height());
    mShowDC.SelectObject(mShowBmp);

    BitBlt(mShowDC,0,0,rectRange.Width(),rectRange.Height(),
        mbkCurveDC,0,0,SRCCOPY);

    //InvalidateRect(rectRange);
    if(boolShowMouseLine)
    {
        mpen.CreatePen(PS_SOLID,1,RGB(0,0,0));
        mOldpen = mShowDC.SelectObject(&mpen);

        mShowDC.MoveTo(rectRange.left,mMousePoint.y);
        mShowDC.LineTo(mMousePoint.x - 1,mMousePoint.y);

        mShowDC.MoveTo(mMousePoint.x + 1,mMousePoint.y);
        mShowDC.LineTo(rectRange.bottom,mMousePoint.y);

        mShowDC.MoveTo(mMousePoint.x,rectRange.top);
        mShowDC.LineTo(mMousePoint.x,mMousePoint.y - 1);

        mShowDC.MoveTo(mMousePoint.x,mMousePoint.y + 1);
        mShowDC.LineTo(mMousePoint.x,rectRange.right);

        mpen.DeleteObject();
        mShowDC.SelectObject(mOldpen);
    }

    mpDC->BitBlt(rectRange.left, rectRange.top,
        rectRange.Width(), rectRange.Height(), 
        &mShowDC, rectRange.left, rectRange.top, SRCCOPY);
```

My another method to draw cross line as follow code

```
 CDC *cdc;
cdc = GetDC();

if(boolShowMouseLine)
{
    cdc->MoveTo(rectRange.left,mMousePoint.y);
    cdc->LineTo(mMousePoint.x - 1,mMousePoint.y);

    cdc->MoveTo(mMousePoint.x + 1,mMousePoint.y);
    cdc->LineTo(rectRange.right,mMousePoint.y);

    cdc->MoveTo(mMousePoint.x,rectRange.top);
    cdc->LineTo(mMousePoint.x,mMousePoint.y - 1);

    cdc->MoveTo(mMousePoint.x,mMousePoint.y + 1);
    cdc->LineTo(mMousePoint.x,rectRange.bottom);
}
```

Current situation is the picture [image]

but this code will draw many cross line when shift the mouse location,

How do I Clear the previous cross line...

Comment: where did you put your drawing code?

Comment: I put my code in OnMouseMove

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the key point to do this without using bitmap is  cdc->SetROP2(R2_NOT).
and you should record the point for the last drawing.
I try to test it by the following steps, hope is will help

1. define  CPoint m_lastPoint in C**view
2. Initilize m_lastPoint =  CPoint(-100,-100) in C**view construct function
3. add OnMouseMove function for the message WM_MOUSEMOVE or other message you want to add.

   CDC *cdc;
       cdc = GetDC();

   ```
   CPoint mMousePoint = point;

   CRect rectRange;//(0,0,500,500);
   GetClientRect(&rectRange);

   if(m_lastPoint.x >= 0 && m_lastPoint.y >= 0)
   {
       cdc->SetROP2(R2_NOT);
       mMousePoint = m_lastPoint;
       cdc->MoveTo(rectRange.left,mMousePoint.y);
       cdc->LineTo(mMousePoint.x - 1,mMousePoint.y);

       cdc->MoveTo(mMousePoint.x + 1,mMousePoint.y);
       cdc->LineTo(rectRange.right,mMousePoint.y);

       cdc->MoveTo(mMousePoint.x,rectRange.top);
       cdc->LineTo(mMousePoint.x,mMousePoint.y - 1);

       cdc->MoveTo(mMousePoint.x,mMousePoint.y + 1);
       cdc->LineTo(mMousePoint.x,rectRange.bottom);
   }
   cdc->SetROP2(R2_BLACK);
   mMousePoint=point;
   cdc->MoveTo(rectRange.left,mMousePoint.y);
   cdc->LineTo(mMousePoint.x - 1,mMousePoint.y);

   cdc->MoveTo(mMousePoint.x + 1,mMousePoint.y);
   cdc->LineTo(rectRange.right,mMousePoint.y);

   cdc->MoveTo(mMousePoint.x,rectRange.top);
   cdc->LineTo(mMousePoint.x,mMousePoint.y - 1);

   cdc->MoveTo(mMousePoint.x,mMousePoint.y + 1);
   cdc->LineTo(mMousePoint.x,rectRange.bottom);
   m_lastPoint = mMousePoint;
   ```

Comment: Unfortunately, the code don't work [Like this picture for result](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ou9nq93mvtt8adw/a.png)

Comment: @user1753112 I don't think SetROP2(R2_NOT) is correct as it is the inverse of the screen color. Try SetROP2(R2_WHITE) just to check (this is not perfect as it will erase the grid lines).

Comment: No way, I can't change the color to white, because I have other curve in the background...

Comment: @user1753112 It is better to store the background for both vertical and horizontal cross lines to a hidden dc using the BitBlt function before drawing the cross-hairs and restore it using BitBlt to your drawing dc for the previous point.

Comment: @user1753112 I suggested changing it to white just for checking

Comment: Can you give me some example code for BitBlt, I am new hand of MFC.

Comment: @user1753112 I see that you have examples of usage in your code. What is wrong with them?

Comment: That code result is large black area in the rect...
[like the picture](https://www.dropbox.com/s/43ujypma4hogryd/b.png)

Comment: No, I need example. I can't understand the pdf file, my english is pool, I am taiwaness strong in chineses.

Comment: @user1753112 Use michaeltang's code, but instead of cdc->SetROP2(R2_BLACK); and cdc->SetROP2(R2_NOT); use cdc->SetROP2(R2_XORPEN);

Comment: the code is working fine in my project, I think it might be related to the way you get the rect object,  use the GetClientRect to get the drawing area in

Comment: I have update my answer related to the initialize part to avoid exception when the mouse is out of the client area & the call of GetClientRect to get the paint area

Comment: hi @michaeltang can you send your project to my mail ys.liang105@gmail.com thanks

Comment: @user1753112, I have sent the project to your email.please check

Comment: @michaeltang your cross line will erase background image, so not adapter to me. I show the new code as above, but it will reflash, not keep in screen.

Comment: Let me ask you, What is your first corss line always remain there?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found an answer for you that doesn't use BitBlt based on micaheltang's answer:
When drawing the line, first call cdc->SetROP2(R2_XORPEN); as stated here http://books.google.co.il/books?id=eDvx4Qx63b0C&pg=PA105&lpg=PA105&dq=MFC+blending+line+with+background&source=bl&ots=v3ycFSlHL7&sig=agpZHLBgnocSXZLQ6qSM6nWFIzM&hl=en&sa=X&ei=wZ_XUsOvLYXStAa054H4Cw&ved=0CCoQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=MFC%20blending%20line%20with%20background&f=false under Line Blending. When erasing the line use the same mode and it should restore the previous color.

Answer (score 0):

I use as follow code

```
CClientDC dc(this);
int oldmode=dc.SetROP2(R2_NOTXORPEN);
        COLORREF color;

        color = RGB(0,0,0);

        CPen pen(PS_DASH, 2, color), *oldpen;
        oldpen = dc.SelectObject(&pen);

        dc.MoveTo(rectRange.left, mMousePoint.y);
        dc.LineTo(mMousePoint.x - 1, mMousePoint.y);

        dc.MoveTo(mMousePoint.x + 1, mMousePoint.y);
        dc.LineTo(rectRange.right, mMousePoint.y);

        dc.MoveTo(mMousePoint.x, rectRange.top);
        dc.LineTo(mMousePoint.x, mMousePoint.y - 1);

        dc.MoveTo(mMousePoint.x, mMousePoint.y + 1);
        dc.LineTo(mMousePoint.x, rectRange.bottom);

        PEndPoint = point;

        dc.MoveTo(rectRange.left, mMousePoint.y);
        dc.LineTo(mMousePoint.x - 1, mMousePoint.y);

        dc.MoveTo(mMousePoint.x + 1, mMousePoint.y);
        dc.LineTo(rectRange.right, mMousePoint.y);

        dc.MoveTo(mMousePoint.x, rectRange.top);
        dc.LineTo(mMousePoint.x, mMousePoint.y - 1);

        dc.MoveTo(mMousePoint.x, mMousePoint.y + 1);
        dc.LineTo(mMousePoint.x, rectRange.bottom);

        dc.SelectObject(oldpen);
        dc.SetROP2(oldmode);
        ReleaseDC(&dc);
```

the cross line will reflash, but no keep in screen, how fixed it.

Comment: You are not storing the old point as micaheltang showed you and instead you are just drawing and then erasing the same cross lines (you are using the same points). You need to use his code, but only change the R2_NOT to RT_XORPEN